# Different types of notation for recursive math?

Tags: arithmetic, recursion

There are particular notations for arithmetic operations on sequences. Ultimately, it is recursive and we are able to shorthand this instead of writing $1+1+1+1+...$ etc.

One example of this is the summation operation:

$$ \sum_{i=0}^N a_i=a_0+a_1+...+a_N $$

Another example is the product operations:

$$ \prod_{i=0}^N a_i=a_0\times a_1\times ...\times a_N$$

My question is: Are there more types of this notation for recursive operation, whether it contains arithmetical meaning or not? I've been trying to look for a proper name for this by looking on Google typing, "Recursive mathematical operations" but I have not found anything. Maybe there's a different name of this algorithm that I am not aware of?

Comment: [Sum-class symbol / accumulation symbol](http://latex.wikia.com/wiki/Sum-class_symbol) in Latex/typesetting terminology.

Comment: I studied these under quantification.  Quantifiers included sum, product, existential, and universal as well as one we defined as $N$ that counted number of * in an array.

Comment: What do you mean by "recursive operation"?

Comment: @JackM Recursive meaning, "repeating the same operation over and over again until there is a conclusion". Kind of like a "for" or "while" loop in a program.

Comment: In programming terminology, the operation of recursively applying a binary operation on a sequence of data is called a [reduce operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not used too commonly, but [Gauss's notation for continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Notations_for_continued_fractions) is an example:

$$
\substack{n\\\Huge \text{K}\\i=1}\frac1{a_i}=\frac{1}{a_1+\frac1{a_2+\frac{1}{a_3+\ddots}}}
$$